# Debugging - CreateProcess under a debugger

Tags: c, windows, debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I'm trying to attach a debugger (Ollydbg v1) to a child process created by `CreateProcess` within another process which is being debugged and I get the following error: "Process is already in debug mode".

My question is why can't I attach a debugger to this process and why the child process is in debug mode although I didn't attach debugger yet and what can I do to create the process in regular mode.

Thanks, Lauren.

**EDIT:**

1. I tried attaching other debuggers as well and all of them produced the same message
2. Furthermore, I tried to create a memory dump of the child process and the `procdump` utility failed because "ReadProcessMemory and/or WriteProcessMemory failed" and therefore produced a dump file of 0 bytes.

Comment: Debuggers generally differ in their feature sets. Some debuggers can only debug a single process, others can automatically attach to child processes. I don't know Ollydbg well enough to, what limitations it has, but you may want to try Visual Studio or WinDbg. You can also configure the system to have a debugger attach to a particular process automatically (see [How to: Launch the Debugger Automatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.90).aspx) for instructions).

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you, I edited my question can you take a look?

Comment: It is probably which debugger is already attached to the parent process that matters more than which debugger you're trying to use on the child process.  Depending on how the parent process was created, the child process may automatically be attached to the same debugger as the parent.  I'm not sure why `procdump` wouldn't be working; perhaps the process is suspended?

Comment: You are attaching OllyDbg to the child process. But which debugger is attached to the parent? Also OllyDbg or something else?

Answer (score 0):

CreateProcess's 6th argument is [dwCreationFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) which can be DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS or DEBUG_PROCESS

**DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS 0x00000002**

The calling thread starts and debugs the new process. It can receive all related debug events using the WaitForDebugEvent function.

**DEBUG_PROCESS 0x00000001**

The calling thread starts and debugs the new process and all child processes created by the new process. It can receive all related debug events using the WaitForDebugEvent function.
A process that uses DEBUG_PROCESS becomes the root of a debugging chain. This continues until another process in the chain is created with DEBUG_PROCESS.
If this flag is combined with DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, the caller debugs only the new process, not any child processes.

The lpProcessAttributes argument also takes a pointer to a [SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-security_descriptor?redirectedfrom=MSDN) structure which may define special security permissions for the created process as well.

I would hook CreateProcess and log those arguments to find out if either of these is being used.

Last thought is, they registered their own debugger to prevent people from attaching their own, sounds like a good anti-debug trick.